# pattern of using EventArgs to cancel events in .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, events, design-patterns, user-interface

In .NET, there is often a pattern to use a property to use events to allow cancellation of events. For example, an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx)

```
    private void OtherInitialize() {
       this.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);
    }

    private void Form1_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
       if (!isDataSaved) {
          e.Cancel = true;
          MessageBox.Show("You must save first.");
       }
       else {
          e.Cancel = false;
          MessageBox.Show("Goodbye.");
       }
    }
```

Is there a name for this pattern, or any article to describe how to implement this patterns (from the view's point of view)? What I can imagine is something like this

```
CancelEventArgs args = new CancelEventArgs();
if(Closing != null)
    Closing(this, args);
if(!args.Cancel)
    DoActualClosing();
```

But I'm not sure if it's this easy. What if there are several event handlers, which handler will determine the eventual value of args.Cancel? What if any (or all) of the handlers throw exception?

Answer (score 0):

> What if there are several event handlers, which handler will determine the eventual value of args.Cancel?

Each handler is called in turn, and can modify args.Cancel.

Currently they are executed in the order they are added, but I believe this is an implementation detail that is not guaranteed.

So, last one wins.  Typically Cancel event handlers only ever set arg.Cancel = true (never reset it to false), so that any event handler can cancel the action.  But there's nothing to stop an event handler from ignoring that convention.

> What if any (or all) of the handlers throw exception?

Then unless you handle it, your application will crash with an unhandled exception.

The implementation you imagine looks correct (it's not thread-safe, but UI events are generally only handled on the UI thread).  I don't know of a name for this pattern.

Comment: how to make it thread safe? If I catch the exception, will the rest of the handlers be executed? About only setting the true, maybe I can create another eventargs where the Cancel is not public and can only be set by some method, e.g. CancelEvent()